# my program creates the file bot not introducing any data

Tags: c

Condition: The data.in file contains 3 values ​​separated by a single space, which represent age, height and
the kind of person. Write a program that determines a person's ideal weight
knowing the height, age and gender of the person (f or m). The calculation formulas are:
* Gmasculin = 50 + 0.75 (height-150) + (age-20) / 4
Gfemenin = Gmasculin-10
where height is expressed in cm and age in years. The ideal weight will be displayed on the screen. All
data about the person (age, height, gender, ideal weight) will be written in the data.out file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() 
{
    int v,i,n;
    char sex[20];
    float s,g,l;
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("file.txt","w");
    printf("Enter the number of people:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the genre\n");
        scanf("%s",sex);
        printf("Enter the height\n");
        scanf("%f",&s);
        printf("Enter the age\n");
        scanf("%d",&v);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(sex == "m")
        {
            g=50+0,75*(s-150)+(v-20)/4;
            printf("the ideal weight of the man is %f\n",g);
        }
        if(sex == "f")
        {
            g=50+0,75*(s-150)+(v-20)/4;
            l=g-10;
            printf("the ideal weight of the woman is %f\n",l);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);

}
```

as i said the "file.txt" is created but not introducing any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sex == "m"` is not how you should compare c-strings. Use `strcmp` or use single quotes for comparing a character.

Besides, to write to a file you should use `fprintf` or something similar.

Moreover, you are overwriting the same memory location in the first `for` loop - perhaps this is not what you wanted. How about using an [array](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson8.html)? Or, putting  everything in one loop and writing to the file every time you read the inputs.